# Russian signs for my clothes shop

Tags: перевод

I would like to display a sign in Russian in my shop which directs my customers not to try on the clothing.  Something like "Please do not try on the clothing"

Would someone be kind enough to provide me with text which would make this clear to my Russian customers?

Answer (score 6):

The translation would be **"Пожалуйста, не примеряйте одежду"**

Comment: Thank you very much. what a helpful (and beautiful) person you are.